# Using local memory for caching in Azure Cloud service worker role

Tags: azure, caching, azure-worker-roles

We are using Azure Cloud Service Worker Roles for processing certain events and most of the time the workers perform these operation:

- Get a message from service bus (this is done concurrently)
- Retrieve certain data from Document DB (2 or more `i/o` calls)
- Perform certain computation
- Update data to Document DB

Now we'd like to store some part of data to local memory (primary) or secondary and leverage that rather than reading the same data again from DB; We'd like to continue to persist latest updates to DB so that's there;

Is there a design pattern around this? Or a library / package that abstracts the logic and provide safe caching? If there is something that provides two layer of caching - first main memory, then secondary and then the DB it'd be awesome

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you look beyond service worker and move to service fabric stateful service. We are using it for similar scenarios where we read data from dB when application starts and later everything is served from service fabric cache. We were able to achieve latency of milliseconds for our services this way. We avoided using redis cache for two reasons one was latency and other was cost.

I can share more information if needed.

Comment: Yeah that's one way to go, but as of now I'm really looking forward to test how primary memory of a VM instance could be leveraged for caching;

Comment: You can install redis locally on the vm , otherwise utilize memory cache class in .net https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: worker roles are provided as PAAS solution, not sure if we can install redis separately there? If that's possible then we should be able to install some sort of DHT across instances - that'd be really cool;

Comment: Yea , your best bet would be to use memory cache object. It’s meant for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [`Cache-Aside Pattern`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cache-aside) for this. However I would strongly recommend against using local/in-memory cache as the cache repository and recommend using a centralized cache repository like `Azure Redis Cache` service.

Reason against using local/in-memory cache is the problems with invalidating the cache especially in multi-instance scenario. In a single instance scenario, using a local/in-memory cache should be fine.

Let me explain with an example.

Let's assume you go with in-memory cache and running two instances.

Instance 1 gets the message, looks for the data in its local cache. It will not find that data in its local cache so it fetches the data from DocumentDB. It will processes the data and puts that in its local cache.

Some time later instance 2 gets the message. Again, it will not find the data in its local cache so it will fetch the data from DocumentDB updates it and then puts that in its cache.

Now at this time data in cache in two instances is different and that will create a problem for you. If for some reason Instance 1 need to work on the same data, it will work with an older version of data because it will find that data in its local cache.

With centralized cache both instances will be updating and using the same cache store, so you will not run into this kind of issue there.

Comment: Doesn't using Redis cache brings in I/O latency? how is it better than directly using the DB?

Comment: let's say the multi instance problem is fine with us, that is, each role will maintain a local cache and only perform full read for a large object if the etag has changed as compared to that in cache;
In that case is there a known pattern or module that will abstract the caching logic? thus taking away pain of memory management, expiry etc?

Comment: Redis holds the data in memory so reads will be much faster than reading from DocumentDB which I’m assuming will perform an additional I/O operation. Etag based approach should work but then you’ll be making multiple trips (possibly) for updates.